# Unable to generate Spring Rest Docs using Gradle. Works with Maven though

Tags: maven, gradle, spring-restdocs

I need help with generating the rest docs using **Gradle**. Maven works for, but not Gradle.

I have a simple project to help with the solution -> https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-rest-docs

When I run using Maven

```
mvn clean package
```

I see the rest docs getting created -> `/target/generated-docs/api-guide.html`

However, when I run using Gradle

```
gradle clean asciidoctor
```

I notice that the snippets are not getting generated -> **`"/build/generated-snippets/“`** is empty. And consequently **`“/build/docs/html5/api-guide.html”`** is empty.

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Sure -> https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-rest-docs/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was explained in gitter, the Spring REST Docs project is designed to output snippets into one directory as specified in the configuration.  In this case, it goes to the maven output directory and not the gradle build directory.

Comment: Thanks @jstrater for elaborating it on Gitter. Once I removed the maven files, it worked well. https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-rest-docs is setup for use.